# Create an array of objects from two different arrays

Tags: javascript

I am having to different arrays. For eg :

Array 1 is :

```
[536, 549]
```

Array 2 is :

```
[
    { text: "ABCD", value: 341 },
    { text: "WXYZ", value: 439 }
]
```

I want to create an object as:

```
[
    {
        fieldId: 536,
        value: {
            value: 341,
            display_value: "ABCD"
        }
    },
    {
        fieldId: 549,
        value: {
            value: 439,
            display_value: "WXYZ"
        }
    }
]
```

I have no idea how to do this. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: all you need is for loop and new array

Comment: @pwolaq can you tell me how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const arr_1 = [536, 549]
const arr_2 = [{text: "ABCD", value: 341},{text: "WXYZ", value: 439}]

// with map
let new_arr = arr_2.map( (ele, index) => {
  return {
    fieldID: arr_1[index],
    value: { value: ele.value, display_value: ele.text }
  };
});

// with for loop
let new_arr2 = [];
for(let i = 0; i < arr_2.length; i++){
  new_arr2.append({
    fieldID: arr_1[i],
    value: { value: arr_1[i].value, display_value: arr_1[i].text }
  });
}
```

Documentation for map():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Documentation for arrays:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array

Documentation for objects:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Not sure if it is desired to have the numbers as string. You would have to use `toString()`. Also not sure if it should be a json string in the end, to get that use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: I am not getting the object as I desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr1 = [ 536, 549 ];
const arr2 = [
    { text: "ABCD", value: 341 },
    { text: "WXYZ", value: 439 }
];

const result = arr1.map((value, index) => ({
    fieldId: value,
    value: {
        display_value: arr2[index].text,
        value: arr2[index].value
    }
}));
```

Here, `result` will hold the desired value.